# Office js Web Addin failing to ExpandDL with soap call

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I'm currently working with an Outlook Web Add-in with Office.js. In this project, we require sending mail merge emails to handle Distribution Lists and Groups. We use the ExpandDL call and our soap request looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="Exchange2013" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:ExpandDL>
      <m:Mailbox>
        <t:EmailAddress>exampledl@example.com</t:EmailAddress>
      </m:Mailbox>
    </m:ExpandDL>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Our outlook web add-in was working until the recent version of **outlook on mac 16.23 (190309)**. I tested the same thing with an older version older version (**16.16**) and it worked fine; it returns with the appropriate results for the ExpandDL call.

I traced the code to the file `outlook-mac-16.00.js` (included from including the office.js library in our web add-in) and ran into this error:

> The operation failed.

What's strange is that it was in the middle of formulating the error response but when we add breakpoints to the error and success callbacks, it never hits. The async soap call never returns to execute any callbacks. We had to step into the library to find the above message.

**Update: [4/15/2019]**

I updated my stable version to **16.23.1 (190326)** and we not get another error for the expandDL call:

> message: "Internal protocol error: '-2147467259'."
>   name: "AccessRestricted"

The above was extracted from `createAsyncResult` on line 10914 from `outlook-mac-16.00.js` when debugging on my current stable version.

**Update: [4/18/2019]**

I updated to the latest stable version **16.24 (19041401)** and this now returns status as `"succeeded"` but the value of the async result is `null`. To be sure, I tried the `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync` call manually to double check, and the results were the same (`null` value and `"succeeded"` status).

I can provide any details on the issue if needed.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the version? for me ExpandDL EWS request works on Outlook for Mac 16.23 (190309). Just to rule out permissions issues, is your manifest still requesting ReadWriteMailbox permission? By any chance is this a delegate mailbox scenario?

Comment: @SureshGowthamS: The version is Outlook for Mac version is the same as your. We are indeed requesting for ReadWriteMailbox permission but it's not a delegate mailbox scenario. We're using the `makeEwsRequestAsync` to make the appropriate ExpandDL call here.

Comment: I am also experiencing this behavior.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Seeing this issue as well

Comment: I am also seeing this behavior.

Comment: We cannot reproduce the issue. Please share details about the Mac OS version and if possible share your manifest, we will install and try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest [insider builds](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outlook-for-mac-release-notes-for-insider-fast-builds-d6347358-5613-433e-a49e-a9a0e8e0462a) and check if the issue is fixed?

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility: The insider build fixed the issue for me. If you still want to reproduce the issue let me know, and I will update my post with the manifest.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility Do you have an ETA on when the latest insider build will be released for everybody?

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility: Is there a support place where I can ask about the release date for the next Outlook for Mac Slow build? We're looking to plan around the release of the version with the fix.

Comment: @Jack the latest production build (16.24) should have the fix. The latest Insider Slow build should have it as well.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility: As stated in my update above, we've now updated to the latest prod build (16.24) and tested it. It's now giving a `succeeded` status with `null` value in the async results. I also tested the `makeEwsRequestAsync` call manually and it returns the same thing.

Comment: @Jack we're able to reproduce the succeeded-null issue, and we're working on a fix. We'll update this thread once we do.

Comment: Hey @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility, any updates on this issue?

Comment: @Jack We are still working on this on priority. We're having trouble reproducing this on our dev builds, which is causing the delay. We'll update here as soon as we have a fix.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility: Is there anything I can provide to help facilitate the fix? You mentioned that you were able to reproduce the succeeded-null issue, but having trouble doing so in your dev builds. Let me know and I can update the post with any info that would potentially be of help.

Comment: Hey @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility, can we have an update and ETA on when the next release will be with the fix?

Comment: @Jack This issue has been fixed and should be available in the next worldwide build. It is already available on the InsiderFast builds if you've signed up for the Insider builds.