# Addin issue with version 16.23

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I had built an Outlook Addin which used to work well in the 16.11 version of the Outlook For Mac. Clicking on the Addin button forwarded that email to another predefined email account.

When I upgraded the Outlook for Mac to 16.23 version, the Addin is unable to send the email. Any help on possible changes in the Outlook for this to happen?

The Addin works as expected on the web and windows.

Comment: Check out the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172557/office-js-web-addin-failing-to-expanddl-with-soap-call) 16.23 has a bug, which got fixed on later versions.

Comment: 16.23 had a bug which is fixed in 16.24 (already out). Could you update Outlook and check if the add-in still doesn't work? We will need more information in that case.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility the emails are still not sent even after updating Outlook to 19041401

Comment: @snowwalker We're currently seeing an issue where the EWS request gives a 'succeeded', but null response. We're working on a fix as soon as possible.